# Error in repository with Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository

I have a problem running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W:The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:Failed to fetch http://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.old-releases.ubuntu.com', 
W:Failed to fetch http://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.old-releases.ubuntu.com', 
W:Failed to fetch http://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.old-releases.ubuntu.com', 
E:Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
W:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

should I add any different repository?

Comment: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ this might help f it is up to date

Comment: @ravery, don't really know what to check, but thanks anyway.

Comment: make the repo list and use those repos

Comment: shouldnt I check some options to create the right list?

Comment: yes of course click the options for your setup and country and everything

Comment: That is what I really don't know. Even if I try with a "basic list" (where I check only things which I know for sure), I still get the same errors.

Comment: germany and xenial right? your mirror should be http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ instead of http://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ the generator could be out of date.